# Move a QThread to another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

For some reason I need to do:

```
class A: Public QThread
class B: class A
```

And now is it possible to do:

```
B myclass;
myclass.moveToThread(workerThread);
```

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason I need to do:

```
class A: Public QThread
class B: class A
```

Unless you're planning on changing how Qt manages threads, I'm sure you can avoid this design.

QThread can be thought of as a thread controller, rather than the thread itself.

As it has been mentioned many times in these forums, a better design for using QThread is to create an object derived from QObject and move that to the QThread object.

Note that an instance of QThread has affinity with the thread in which it is created *[("It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it")](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)*. This design allows the original thread to communicate with the new QThread instance via signals and slots. For this reason, it's not really a great idea to inherit from QThread, derive another class from it and move it to itself!

Answer (score 0):

Discussing design, it is not good when you override the thread class. It is said that we should move some QObject-derived handler to thread of QThread (moveToThread). And deriving directly from QThread is not really justified for most of times. There is a good article explaining why you should rather move another object and to override QThread. **Please read [this](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) and [this](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)**. I can *only* think of a special own event loop override for QThread::exec which makes some sense for solution with QThread override.

As you asked: you can do that. Class B should have override for run() then. Class B should also have, for example onStart and onFinish to make it useful after all.

```
B::B()
{
  moveToThread(this);
}

void B::run() // override
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(onStart()));
  connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()));
  exec();
}

// make sure to create thread object which is not destructed while leaving the scope of the function that creates it
B* pBThreadObj = new B(this);
pBThreadObj->start();
```

Comment: Please, read docs about [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html). How  you can connect `started()` signal at `run()` method? Docs [says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#started) about`started()`: "This signal is emitted from the associated thread when it starts executing, before the run() function is called."